# Naming convention for instances of java.util.Comparator

Tags: java, naming-conventions, comparator, naming

Suppose there is a class stock

```
  class Stock
  {
    String id;
    String name;
  }
```

I want to create two comparators that compare by `id` and `name`, respectively.
Are there naming conventions or best practices for comparators in Java?

Are following names okay?

- `StockByIdComparator` and `StockByNameComparator`
- `SortStockById` and `SortStockByName`

I know that redundant names are avoided in certain areas. One would choose
`List<Stock> stocks` over `List<Stock> stockList`. Also types should not be encoded in variable names (maybe since the rise of IDEs?). But there is also the important dimension of clearness.

So what is a good aproach for naming comparators?

Comment: Do you really need to name them? Isn't  `Comparator.comparing(Stock::getName)` sufficient? My opinion is that your first option is way better. Your second option isn't a name, but a verb, suitable for a method, not an object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally, I would name them as `StockByIdComparator` and `StockByNameComparator`.
It may appear a little bit redundant but it is clear as every Java developer knows what a `Comparator` is.

I like less `SortStockById` and `SortStockByName` as

- they look like method names  : start by a verb and followed by a complement.
- I cannot know right know that these are `Comparator` implementations.

I don't think that choosing a name coupled with the `Comparator` interface be a issue or bad naming strategy.
On the contrary, it is an interface and it makes part of the Java base API.

Answer (score 2):

If you create them as a class I would include Comparator there

```
class StockByIdComparator implements Comparator<Stock> {}
```

If you want to create it as a variable or constant - you can skip it

```
static final Comparator<Stock> COMPARE_BY_ID = new Comparator<Stock>() {}
```

so it would look like this

```
Collections.sort(stocks, COMPARE_BY_ID);
```

Answer (score 1):

`StockByIdComparator` and `StockByNameComparator` are ok, since they describe the purpose of these classes. But I would name them like `StockComparatorById` and `StockComparatorByName` respectively, so they will have one general prefix. So in future, you will be able to find all `StockComparator*` easily.

Basically, there is no any best practice for naming Comparators or other interface implementations. The good way is to choose descriptive and not very long name and keep this name "convention" along with all code.